# php function/script for combining 2 columns in a database and remove their special characters and spaces

Tags: php, mysql

hi im trying to write a script that will update my database using php

i need to combine two columns from the database, remove their special characters and spaces and insert the result inside the third column of my database

```
fn        ln       result
Super-     Man      sman
Bat&       Man      bman
Wonder -   Woman    wwoman
```

i cant seem to get the result i want with my script

```
    <?php
    include('connect2.php');

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * from alumni");
    $query = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    while($query){
    $query[ln] = str_replace(" ", "", $query[ln]); 
    $query[fn] = str_replace(" ", "", $query[fn]); 

    $query[ln] = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $query[ln]);
    $query[fn] = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $query[fn]);

    $query[ln] = strtolower($query[ln]);
    $query[fn] = strtolower($query[fn]);

    $query[fn] = substr($query[fn],0,1);

    printf($username = $query[fn] . $query[ln]);



    mysql_query("UPDATE alumni SET username='$username' WHERE alumni_id = $query[alumni_id]") or die(mysql_error());    
    }

    ?>
```

can anyone help me?
thanks in advance

****EDIT************
finally got it working

```
    <?php
    include('connect2.php');

    $b = mysql_query("SELECT * from alumni");

    while($a = mysql_fetch_array($b)){
        //echo $a[fn];
    $ln = str_replace(" ", "", $a[ln]); 
    $fn = str_replace(" ", "", $a[fn]); 

    $ln = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $ln);
    $fn = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $fn);

    $ln = strtolower($ln);
    $fn = strtolower($fn);

    $fn = substr($fn,0,1);

    printf($username = $fn . $ln);



    mysql_query("UPDATE alumni SET username='$username' where alumni_id = $a[alumni_id]") or die(mysql_error());    
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see several issues in your code, but the biggest one to note is the following:

```
 $query = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

The mysql_fetch_array function receives a result set and returns and array for the record to be fetched.  With this instruction, you are replacing your result set with the array, and if you lost the result set, you will not be able to fetch for further records.

By the way, you are not geting the next record within your loop.  There's another problem I see.